# any complete metric space $S$ can be homeomorphically embedded as a dense subset of a compact metric space $\bar{S}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

How to prove that any complete metric space $S$ can be homeomorphically embedded as a dense subset of a compact metric space $\bar{S}$.

I know that a polish space is homeomorphic  to a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $[0,1]^{\infty}$. Does the above trivially follows from this ? I don't see it. $G_{\delta}$'s need not be dense.

Comment: Not every complete metric space is Polish. And that makes the assertion wrong. For Polish spaces, just consider the closure of the image of the embedding.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from that: embed $X$ into $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ using $e$, so that $e$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $e[X] \subseteq [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$.

Then $\overline{e[X]}$ is compact (closed in the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$) and by definition contains $e[X]$ (which is essentially $X$) as a dense subspace.

Note that we do not need completeness or being $G_\delta$, it wil work for any separable metric space. And separable is necessary of course, as a compact metric space is second countable, and so should $X$ be. So the correct statement is: every separable (!) metric space can be homeomorphically embedded as a dense subspace of a compact metric space.